# no sound and tried answers in the exchange but not working - need help

Tags: sound, dell, inspiron, output

using ubuntu 14.04, did upgrade and sound disappeared.  I tried 
pulseaudio -k gave Failed to kill daemon: No such process

someone mentioned that they killed the pulseaudio process directly and it worked.  how do I do that?

also tried pacmd list-cards but that gave 0 card(s) available.

I have a Dell Inspiron 15-3552

Comment: This question is specific to an [end of life](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) Ubuntu release. These are no longer supported and are therefore off-topic here. To upgrade, see: [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: I don't understand your answer whatsoever.  how should I pose my question then, for it not to be off topic???

Comment: are you saying that I did the wrong upgrade which is why the sound disappeared?

Comment: I'm saying that 14.04 is no longer supported. Please read https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_Life_.28EOL.29 and https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: in 2017, I experienced problems and was told to do an upgrade to 16.04 which I did and all my problems went away, but my system still shows 14.04 so I don't know if the upgrade happened.  I tried all the instructions given in the link and when I get to do-release-upgrade, it says, no new release found

Comment: sorry, to clarify, just now (May 2019), I tried all the instructions given in the link and when I get to do-release-upgrade, it says no new release found

Comment: so how do I get the latest ubuntu?

Comment: so I followed the link you gave for installing software or upgrade from old unsupported release and it didn't work.  all I got was errors and fails.  where should I go now to find answers?  I feel that I shouldn't be asking a question so how should I even ask the thread to the link you gave?  how does one use this StackExchange????  why is this so hard?  too many comments, I don't what should I be following.....

Comment: Take a look at https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0. But make sure your computer has the minimum specifications.

Comment: so apparently I already have 16.04 so I should not have done the # gedit /etc/apt/sources.list to change to old-release-upgrade.  now, no matter what I do, it's showing errors and fails.  I tried undoing the # gedit /etc/spt/sources.list but it won't give me the sources.list.  I think my ubuntu is completely screwed up. thanks a lot !!